# Redux Thunk conditional http requests

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

I'm working with Redux Thunk in my React application, where i am making some conditional checks in regards to checking if there is already data in the store

Currently my logic looks something like this (this is just an example, but the same pattern is implemented throughout the application)

```js
    const {actions: initialData, loading: loadingActions, error: errorActions} = useSelector(state => state.getActionsReducer)
   
    useEffect(() => {

        if(isEqual(initialData, initialActionState.actions)){
        //indtil videre bliver alle redux actions bare kaldt i useEffect
        allActions.initialStateActions.getLevelData(dispatch)
        allActions.initialStateActions.getActionsData(dispatch)
        }

    }, [loadingActions, initialData, dispatch])
```

I tried the same thing without the conditional check, and the functionality seemed to be the same.

Is this check redundant?

Answer (score 0):

If `initialData` or any of the objects inside the dependency array does not change throughout the usage of the application, then that check is redundant, as it is only executed once.

However, if your `loadingActions` change, the `useEffect` is fired again and that check would come into play.

It would need more investigation to decide if the check is redundant or not.